# Using old D-Link Wifi stick

Tags: hardware, kodi, wifi, driver, wpa

My brand new raspi just arrived. I played around with raspbmc and did like it. Now I have an old D-Link DWL-122 Wifi stick flying around and I'd love to use it as the WIFI device.

So, is it possible to reuse it as wifi device at my raspi? What do I have to do to configure it

- in raspbmc
- in debian
  ?

Any hints appreciated!

BTW: lsusb says:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 07d1:3c0f D-Link AirPlus G DWL-G122 Wireless Adapter (rev.E1) [Ralink RT2070]
```

UPDATE:
so, meanwhile, I got it running using the XBMC addon called "network manager".

Now I cannot figure out how to use WPA2 instead of WEP. All listed networks show up as "WEP", no matter if they are WPA2. Is this a problem with XBMC, the D-Link or the raspi?

Comment: Could you add output from the following commands to your question?
    ifconfig
    iwconfig

Comment: Ralink sounds promising. Have a look at what `dmesg` says about it. What "configuring it" means depends on what you want it to do (probably network access or access point and there should be guides for setting up both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Debian`, there is a `WiFi` utility icon on the desktop and in the menu on the latest version. I don't know about `Raspbmc`. To get to it go to the menu > `Internet` > `wpa_gui` and select your device and then your network. I had to play around with the settings but it eventually connected. Then I did `sudo apt-get install firmware-ralink` for security and performance enhancements (don't know if this is necessary but it's a good idea.) Then I rebooted using `sudo reboot` and it worked perfectly.

P.S. I used a Reltek stack and changed the "Ralink" command to "Reltek" and it worked with no additional drivers/firmware. You need the latest Debian from** [Raspberry Pi's website](http://www.raspberrypi.org) **for this to work.

Comment: indeed, the latest linux seems to include drivers for that old piece of hardware. now setting it up with WPA2 is the next hurdle.

Comment: @honestor I don't know if WPA2 would be harder, I've used different encryptions and there are textboxes you can type in the password after selecting the SSID. [This tutorial](http://kerneldriver.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/configuring-wpa2-using-wpa_supplicant-on-the-raspberry-pi/) might help you; I didn't look at it much but seems to be what you need. This is a command line solution so I don't know how permanent/automatic it is after a reboot. However there are workarounds that you can have a command executed at each boot.